# Create address element for webform to output country code

Tags: 8, webforms

I'd like to create a field using `webform` that accepts a country but outputs the country code.

I'm guessing one path forward is to find the handler used by contrib and extend it? Or is that functionality already in the plugin and hiding in plain sight?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple - for Basic address, click edit, then uncheck everything but "country" and select `Country codes`
[image]